# Check typeof Account

Tags: c#, .net, types

I am trying some new things and I'm running into a problem. I know something is missing from this but I don't know what it is.

I have a class (`Account`) and an enum `AccountType` and what I would like to do is to create a new Account:

```
Account account = new Account()
{
   // Make it known that this particular account is of type TransactionAccount.
}

public enum TypeOf
{
   Transaction,
   Savings
}

public TypeOf AccountType { get; set; }
```

So that later on I may do something like:

`if(account.AccountType == TypeOf.Transaction) { // Do something. }`

or:

`if(account is AccountType.Savings) { // Do something. }`, etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class design will work in principle. You only have to store the account type:

```
Account account = new Account()
{
    AccountType = TypeOf.Transaction,
};
```

You should probably rename `TypeOf` to `AccountType`. What does "TypeOf" mean when you just hear it? It means nothing. Not a good name.

Comment: I can't rename TypeOf to AccountType because AccountType is already defined for something else. That wouldn't be "valid", would it?

Comment: @Aeron you can't have two types with the same name but you can have a type and a property with the same name. That said, if you have two things named that way the name is not expressive enough. Names should be unambigous. Give one of those things a more expressive name. But certainly change TypeOf. Maybe AccountTypeEnum if AccountType is taken.

Comment: Oh thank you so much @usr. Now I don't have to come up with silly alternative names just for the sake of having to have something unique.

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to do will violate Liskov Substitution Principle. A better design will be to have subclasses of Account and take advantage of polymorphism.

This way you also comply to Open-closed Principle and you will not have to add new `if` branches when a new type of Account appears in the picture.

Comment: I guess... I just felt like doing something differently for a change. Isn't there another way?

Comment: According to this argument you could pretty much never use enums as fields. That is not true. Neither is this argument. I don't see why an account can't have a type but have pretty much the same fields and behavior for all types. Also, the account type might change.

Comment: You are over interpreting the answer, I did not said never, but generally when you have code like the one in the question the principles are violated. The question did not provide any insights into the business requirements so the change vectors are unknown. As I said in the previous comment, it depends on info that was not available